# Cognos Scheduling Multiple Parameter job

Tags: parameters, prompt, jobs, schedule, cognos

I have to schedule a .CSV report to run everynight for each Organisation in my Organisation_Table, then save this report to a directory in my file system specific to the organisation.

There could be 100s of individual organisations though, is there any way to only make one schedule and loop the prompt screen to go through each organisation?

or will i need to create a schedule job for each organisation(possibly 100s) and give the prompt screen variables for each organisation?

thanks

Comment: There's the concept of "bursting" in Cognos which allows you to distribute a report to all instances of a dimension. It's very likely that you can also use this in the specific context of CSV reports.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I looked into this after you mentioned it and think i bill try and build my report with the bursting idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need a query to pull a list of the organziations.  You can use the list of organizations to setup Bursting, where the report will create seperate copies of itself for each iteration of a list.

File->Burst Options

Once you select a list of organizations to include in the burst, you will setup the burst query to feed its organization code (or name, unique id, whatever you are using to identify organizations in the database) into your main query.  Each time it runs an organization in your burst, it will filter the main query to only include data for the current organization in the burst sequence.

Bursts can be done to email, or to the Hard Drive (save the reports).

Two guides that outline the basics of bursting in Cognos:

http://www.ironsidegroup.com/2014/07/15/creating-a-burst-table-for-a-cognos-report/
http://www.clickdwh.com/Pages/Author_Bursting_Report.aspx

Comment: Thanks Damien, i think i going going to do exactly as you have said.  I never knew about the bursting feature before but it seems exactly what i need.